# Install addons on Odoo V.15 with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to install custom modules from OCA GitHub to my initial setup which is installed via Docker container.

I am quite lost on how to perform to install the modules in my environment.
I have done my initial odoo setup up and running via https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-odoo-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-docker.

The system is up and running without issue but I am not able to install custom modules from third parties like OCA.

**My docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  odoo:
    image: odoo:15.0
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

volumes:
  data:
  db:
```

File Directory right now:

```
./addons  ----> I am placing the module files inside this folder.
./docker-compose.yml
```

then I run the `docker-compose up -d` then I go to odoo and update list but cannot see the modules.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `/mnt/extra-addons` to the `addons_path` parameter in Odoo configuration file (`odoo.conf`).

For example:

```
addons_path = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons,/mnt/extra_addons
```

You have to enable `developer mode` and then go to `Apps` and  press `Update App List`   to update the list of apps.

Comment: I have created /config folder under the same folder with docker-compose.yml. Then created the odoo.conf file with `[options]` <br/>
`addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons` <br/>
`data_dir = /var/lib/odoo` <br/> .... I also added `- ./config:/etc/odoo` to docker-compose.yml but I cannot see the addons that I have put inside addons folder inside the app

Comment: You configuration now looks good, make sure the custom module folder is not nested, also when you open apps click on update app list to update the list of apps.

Comment: the folder structure is like in the link https://imgur.com/a/lJ9v0WI. and the module under addons folder is like https://imgur.com/a/5aILT3s

Comment: looks like at least some of your add-ons are nested. I think you can flatten them.

Comment: @Paxmees thanks for your comment but I dont think that the nested folders are the issue  here. please check the folder structure screenshot from my setup. https://imgur.com/a/uZViTu1

Comment: @jakarina
  Did you update the app lists?

Comment: @WaleedMohsen yes. I have checked the file system inside the container, and it looks the mnt/extra-addons file is empty.

Comment: @WaleedMohsen Somehow `docker-compose` is not working properly and not copying local addon files into addons location of the container.

Comment: What about conf file is it showing, I think you have a permission issue with your ```./addons``` folder so docker couldn't read from the folder.